# passing the values to a function

Tags: python

I have a function that returns the replaced values correctly, but for some reason, the run_instances function receives the entire string as a single object (instead of 4 separate values).

```
import boto
ec2_conn = boto.connect_ec2(aws_access_key_id='XXX', aws_secret_access_key='XXX')

ami='ami-XXX'
key_name='XXX15a.pem'
instance_type='t1.macro'

aid="image_id='%s', placement='us-east-1a', key_name='%s', instance_type='%s'" % (ami, key_name, instance_type)
```

When I try to execute the run_instances function...

```
ec2_conn.run_instances(aid)

<Message>Invalid id: "image_id='ami-XXX', placement='us-east-1a', key_name='XXX.pem', instance_type='t1.macro'" (expecting "ami-...")</Message>
```

Is there any way to pass the values to the function correctly?

Comment: Err... `run_instances(image_id=ami, placement='us-east-1a', ...)`...!?

Comment: It is a simplified version of a class. I know this but I will like to pass the values as variable for some other reason.

Comment: *"for some reason, the run_instances function receives the entire string as a single object"* - what do you mean "for some reason"? Why on earth would you expect any different?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying the problem statement to: *how to pass multiple variables around so they can be passed into a function later on without passing all variables individually...*:

```
params = dict(ami='ami-XXX', key_name='XXX15a.pem', instance_type='t1.macro', placement='us-east-1a')
ec2_conn.run_instances(**params)
```

Store them in a dict and expand them to keyword arguments with `**`.

Comment: Thanks. The second line is working correctly. While creating the dict as shown on the first line, I get an error while trying to replace the variables with %s

Comment: Why are you trying to replace the variables with `%s`? It's not string interpolation, pass your values directly.

Comment: To be extremely explicit, if you need to use variables, use variables: `dict(ami=ami, key_name=key_name, ...)`. That'll use your variables defined above to construct the dict. A different way to write the same thing is `{'ami': ami, 'key_name': key_name, ...}`; maybe that makes it slightly more obvious what's going on. But why write them as separate variables in the first place? Just write literally what you see above.